# Django channels socket.send() not sending data

Tags: javascript, python, django, sockets

I'm using web sockets built from Django Channels and I have a small Javascript function that when added in my template, should send data to the web sockets via a `urls.py` type file called `routing.py` and into a views type file called `consumers.py`. When I render this template on the browser and go to the browser console and hit `socket.send("hi")`, it pings me back with data, but I have this command in my code anyway, why isn't getting executed when the page loads? My code should explain the scenario better

My template:

```
{% block javascript %}
{{ block.super }}

var socket = get_websocket('/echo2/');    //Echo2 is the route in route.py
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log( e.data );
}                                                                                                                                                     
socket.send('hi');    //This line isn't being executed, why?

{% endblock javascript %}
```

Routing.py:

```
from channels.routing import route
channel_routing = [
route("websocket.receive", consumers.ws_echo2_message, path='^/echo2/$'),
]
```

Consumers.py

```
def ws_echo2_message( message ):

    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': json.dumps({
            'message': message.content['text'],
            'dave': 'hi'
        })
    },
                               immediately = True)

    time.sleep(2)

    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': message.content['text'],
    },
                               immediately = True)

    time.sleep(2)

    message.reply_channel.send({
        'text': message.content['text'],
    },
                               immediately = True)
```

When I go to my browser console and say `socket.send('hi'), it gives me this:

```
>socket.send("HI");
> {"message": "HI", "dave": "hi"}
> HI
```

So, if `socket.send' works in the console, why not work in the template?

Comment: hey, did you solve your problem ?

Comment: I did not actually! This is so old, I even forgot it existed, I think I ended up using a different approach to it. Did not go the socket route at all. Sorry!